# Function not reading from stdin properly

Tags: c, function, computer-science, stdin

So I've been trying to write a virtual computer program that reads in data from stdin. The stdin keeps coming in the form of (`%d %s %d`), the data basically represents a program with a certain task and looks like this:

```
01 READ 60
02 LOAD 60
03 SUB 61
04 STOR 60
05 BRNG 15
06 READ 70
07 LOAD 70
08 ADD 80
09 STOR 80
10 LOAD 60
11 SUB 61
12 STOR 60
13 BRNG 15
14 BRAN 6
15 WRIT 80
16 HALT 99
61 SET 1
80 SET 0
```

There is a function that works as a compiler and is supposed to read in those data line by line, but for some reason whenever this function runs I get **"improper format program will now exit"**. I've been trying to figure out why it's doing that for a while now with no clue.

The program reads in stdin stream line by line, and it should stop when there is no more stdin and it should check if the format is correct, and it is indeed in the correct format so why is it not reading it properly? My personal guess was that it's not reading it line by line for some reason but I am not sure if that's it!

PS: I was using file pointers the first time I made this program and it worked completely fine, but when I switched the stream to stdin, it started giving improper format errors!

```
int compile ( int memory [], int* instructionCounter , int* instructionRegister ,int*operationCode ,int* operand){
    char s[80]; /* The buffer */
    *instructionRegister=0;
    *operationCode=0;
    while(((*instructionRegister)=scanf("%d %s %d", operationCode,s,operand)) != NULL){ /*Reads data line by line then stores the integer returned by fscanf to instructionRegister pointer so that I can check for formating */
       if((*instructionRegister) ==3 ){ /*Checks for improper format by comparing the current instructionRegister count to 3, returns improper format otherwise */
            if(*operand >9999|| *operand <0){  /* Checks for word overflow in compiler, makes sure that digits do not exceed 9999 */
                printf("attempts to place a word in memory that is larger than 4 digits, or attempted to pass in a negative value\n ");
                exit(0);
            }
            /*Compares the string section of the code and checks if it matches the following words and then it converts it to it's 4 digit value by adding into it the operand */
            if(strcmp(s,"READ") == 0) {
                memory[*operationCode] = 10 * 100 + *operand;
            }
            else if(strcmp(s,"WRIT") == 0) {
                memory [*operationCode] = 11 * 100 + *operand;
            }
            else if(strcmp(s,"LOAD") ==0){
                memory [*operationCode] = 20 * 100 + *operand;
            }
            else if(strcmp(s,"PRNT") ==0){
                memory [*operationCode] = 12 * 100 + *operand;
            }
            else if(strcmp(s,"STOR") ==0){
                memory [*operationCode] = 21 * 100 + *operand;
            }
            else if(strcmp(s,"SET") ==0){
                memory [*operationCode] = *operand;
            }
            else if(strcmp(s,"ADD") ==0){
                memory [*operationCode] = 30 * 100 + *operand;
            }
            else if(strcmp(s,"SUB") ==0){
                memory [*operationCode] = 31 * 100 + *operand;
            }
            else if(strcmp(s,"DIV") ==0){
                memory [*operationCode] = 32 * 100 + *operand;
            }
            else if(strcmp(s,"MULT") ==0){
                memory [*operationCode] = 33 * 100 + *operand;
            }
            else if(strcmp(s,"MOD") ==0){
                memory [*operationCode] = 34 * 100 + *operand;
            }
            else if(strcmp(s,"BRAN") ==0){
                memory [*operationCode] = 40 * 100 + *operand;
            }
            else if(strcmp(s,"BRNG") ==0){
                memory [*operationCode] = 41 * 100 + *operand;
            }
            else if(strcmp(s,"BRZR") ==0){
                memory [*operationCode] = 42 * 100 + *operand;;
            }
            else if(strcmp(s,"HALT")==0){
                memory [*operationCode] =9999;
            }

            else {   /* Prints back to the user that the compiler did not recognize one of them commands as it was going through it */
                printf ("This is an unknown command, commands are case sensitive, program will now exit \n");
                exit(0);

            }
        }
        else{    /* Returns improper format if instructionRegister does not match 3*/
            printf("Improper Format, program will now exit \n");
            exit(0);
        }

    }
    /* Checks if the instruction data contains a HALT, if not it would terminate */
    while(*instructionCounter<100){
        if (memory[*instructionCounter] == 9999){
            return 1;
        }
        else
            (*instructionCounter)++;
    }
    printf("Halt was not found, program will now exit");
    exit (0);
}
```

The desired purpose of this function is to read in the data line by line and store it in memory virtual cells. It should check for the format of those lines to be `%d %c %d`, so that it can extract the data and store it in the memory accordingly.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with some example of input data and desired behavior.

Comment: You might want to read [a `scanf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). The functions don't return a pointer, so you should not compare the returned value with `NULL`.

Comment: I've switched NULL to feof(stdin) but it was still giving me an error!

Comment: I will edit the post to show an example of input data

Comment: Obviously, if your code prints "improper format", the return value of `scanf` was not 3. If I were in your shoes, I'd be curious what it was instead.

Comment: Yes, it is reading more than 3 arguments for some reason, I am going to print out the pointer

Comment: If I was you I would use e.g. `fgets` to read the lines, then use `sscanf` to parse them. Also, I would use an unspecified  `FILE *` to read from, and simply call the function with `stdin` to read from standard input.

Comment: So should I use fgets in the while loop to read lines into a buffer, then use sscanf to parse them at the beginning of each loop and check for format errors there?

Comment: Well that's what I would do. Then it's much easier to handle errors reading the file, separate from parsing errors. It's also not possible to out of sync with the input (for example if one line has two values and the next line four, one or none). I also recommend you keep track of the current line, it will make it easier to find the error in the input if you print a line-number where it is.

Comment: while(fgets(temp,12,stdin)){
*instructionRegister=sscanf(temp,"%d %s %d", operationCode,s,operand);

Comment: I've switched my while loop to that but it is still generating improper format :(!

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I figured out the problem , but no idea how to solve it. It seems like at very last input line from stdin , I get overflow

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line:

> ```
> while(((*instructionRegister)=scanf("%d %s %d", operationCode,s,operand)) != NULL){
> ```

The `scanf()` function returns

- the number of successful conversions, which will be anything between 0 and 3, or
- `EOF` in case an input failure (end-of-file or read error) occurs before any successful conversions. The `EOF` macro is some negative number, typically `-1`.

You're comparing the return value to `NULL` which is `0` (or `(void *)0` or similar). With the input that you have provided, the `while` loop will keep reading until `scanf()` returns `EOF`. This will not break out of the `while` loop, but it will fail the next test:

> ```
>     if((*instructionRegister) ==3 ){ 
>         /* big snip */
>     else{
>         printf("Improper Format, program will now exit \n");
>         exit(0);
>     }
> ```

The solution is, of course, to compare the result to `EOF` instead of `NULL`.

---

There is also a potential buffer overflow in your `scanf()` call. The `%s` conversion specifier will cause `scanf()` to write beyond the end of the `s[]` buffer if the string is longer than 79 characters. (Don't forget that it will *also* write a terminating `\0`.)

You can limit the amount by adding a maximum field width:

```
scanf ("%d %79s %d", /*...*/)
```

If the input string is longer than 79 characters, the input will fail to match the whitespace before the `"%d"` modifier and `scanf()` will return `2` to indicate the incomplete result.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering but I'm getting overflows still! Floating point and word overflows , I think that Scanf is not scanning properly. Before I made the modification to my program I was scanning from a file using fscanf and the program was working fine, but when I switched to STDIN it won't work anymore.

Comment: @Mohammed: There is no floating point anywhere in the code that you have posted. Perhaps you should post a new question with code that is relevant to those problems.

Comment: I can post the entire program but it's long.  Basically I have two functions that check for errors:                                                                          int checkSegmentationFault(int *operand)
{
    if(*operand < 0 || *operand >100){
        printf("SEGMENTATION FAULT: Attempted to access an unknown address \n");
        exit(0);
    }
    return 0;
}

Comment: int checkWordFlow( int instructionCounter, int memory []) 
{
    instructionCounter=0;
    while(instructionCounter<100){
        if(memory[instructionCounter]>9999)
        { printf("Word Overflow at memory element %d\n program will exit\n", instructionCounter);
            exit(0);
        }
        instructionCounter++;
    }
    return 1;
}

Comment: When I run the program I get this error : Word Overflow at memory element 70

Comment: @Mohammed: You don't have 70 instructions in the program. You need to keep track of the length of the program and iterate over the _actual_ number of elements, not a predefined `100`.